# Can a 0.5 W resistor be substituted for a 10 W resistor?

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

Can a 2 kΩ, 0.5 W resistor be substituted for a 2 kΩ, 10 W resistor?
Also, what kind of defects would occur?

Comment: only one 1/2 W resistor?

Comment: Not if resistor needs to dissipate >0.5W of power.

Comment: you, it can  if you do not apply any more than 30 V across the resistor

Comment: Welcome. // Looks like you should spend some time on the relationships between R and P: U = R * I, P = U * I = U^2/R = I^2*R.

Answer (score 4):

No. Here's why:

As current flows through a resistor, heat is generated as electrical power is dissipated. That heat flows out through the walls of the resistor, the inside of which is hot.

Too much power dissipation causes the temperature inside the resistor to climb high enough that the resistor gets hot enough to self-destruct, and catch fire. In the world of engineering, this is called a *Bad Thing*.

Resistors intended to dissipate lots of watts are made physically big to give the heat inside a better chance to get out and thereby prevent the resistor from overheating. On the other hand, resistors designed to dissipate only a little bit of a watt can be made tiny.

Putting a resistor rated to dissipate a maximum of 1/2 watt into a circuit where 10 watts must be managed will cause the resistor to almost immediately overheat, blow up, and catch fire.

Comment: to be fair, it can be substituted, just not for long & not very well.